# Direction of angle after reflection

Tags: geometry, angle, maple, triangular

Say if I had a triangle and I was to draw a line towards one of the sides of the triangle, how would I create the reflected line of when that line hits the side of the triangle in Maple. I just drew this quickly in paints (and so its not accurately). Is there a way to do this in maple. Thanks
I currently have,

```
with(plots):
with(plottools):

a:=polygon([[0,0],[2,0],[1,2]]):
b:=polygon([[2,0],[4,0],[3,2]]):
e:=line([2.5,2],[2.5,1]):
f:=line([2.5,1],[1.72,0.484]):

display(a,b,e,f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's starting direction is vector **Dir** `(dir.x, dir.y)`, and side of reflection has unit normal **N** `(n.x, n.y)`

After reflection tangential component of vector is inverted and normal component remains the same. We can use equations below to calculate new direction:

```
dot = dir.x * n.x + dir.y * n.y

//after reflection
newdir.x = dir.x - 2 * dot * n.x
newdir.y = dir.y - 2 * dot * n.y
```

Apply such transformations to get a sequence of reflections from right and left triangle sides (using corresponding normals)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm still a little confused on how to actually apply this? Also is this in Maple or Matlab?

Comment: It is just set of formulas. I think it is not hard to implement them in Maple. Perhaps Maple has some inbuilt possibility to work with vectors  - it would simplify the task.

Comment: I’m sure it’s really easy, but it’s just taking ages to get my head around it, is it possible if you could just post an example of any line hitting at any angle and then I can work it out from there. Thanks

Comment: @Jerry It would better if you make code piece with defining input data and calculations. Then we could help to correct it and elaborate full solution. This is how SO works...

Comment: I got this far, but I have just been adding the coordinates in manually, I knew I could do it this way, I just thought there might be an equation or something that I could use to simplify it and make is more accurate. Here's the code I have so far; a:=polygon([[0,0],[2,0],[1,2]]);
b:=polygon([[2,0],[4,0],[3,2]]);
e:=line([2.5,2],[2.5,1]);
f:=line([2.5,1],[1.72,0.484]);
display(a,b,e,f);

Comment: Edit your question and add reproducible Maple code in it. I don't know what packages should be included to use these commands.

Comment: @MBo Sorry I forgot to add the package, I edited the question.